# haskell parsec problem

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am newbie haskell and in lernning parsec lib
a example :

```
nesting :: Parser Int
nesting = do{ char '('
            ; n <- nesting
            ; char ')'
            ; m <- nesting
            ; return (max (n+1) m)
            }
        <|> return 0
```

so what's n or m? why n and m is int and greater than 0?

Comment: I got it !! return (n+1) for every '(' ,so n is '(' level

Comment: BTW, you neither need the curly braces nor the `;` for do-notation.

Answer (score 3):

Parsec is a monadic parsing library, so you probably should first introduce yourself to monads and the syntactic sugar that is the do notation.

`nesting` is a parser which you can see as a computation (monad) with a result of type `Int`.
Whenever you see code like this `n <- nesting` in a do block, it means run the monad nesting and bind the result to `n`.

To see how this parser works try running it by hand. For example use the string  "`()`".

It goes like this:

- Tries the parser in the do block, succeeds parsing '`(`', runs the parser recursively and binds the result to `n`.

  - Tries the parser in the do block, fails parsing '`(`', tries the next parser (`return 0`) which always succeeds with the value `0`.
- `n` now has the value 0, because that was the result of running the parser recursively. Next in the do block is the parser `char ')'`, it succeeds, calls the parser again recursively and binds the result to `m`. Same as above the result in `m` is `0`.

Now the whole result of the computation is `max (n+1) m` which is `1`.

As you can see this parses nested parenthesis, and roughly at the top level `n` holds the number of `'('` parsed, while `m` holds the number of `')'` parsed.